# Python loop over dataframes and rename results

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, dataframe

I have a series of csv files which I would like to run a script on.  Each file has the same headers and the same number of rows just different data.  So far I have used Pandas to import all csv files from my directory.  I have a list of all files names and a list of dataframes containing the data from each file.

I would like to run a script on each file/dataframe and name the exports with the prefix of the filename.  Is this possible and is a loop the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
fn_list = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']  # list of filenames
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]  # list of dataframes

output_dir = r'C:\temp'

for name, df in zip(fn_list, df_list):
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, name+'.csv'), index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks jp_data_analysis  I'm a bit stuck on the best way to move through the data.  Do you think I should loop and if so am I trying to loop through the files or the dataframes?

Comment: as per my pseudo-code, you are looping through 2 lists: list of filenames (strings) and list of dataframe objects. That's what you have in your question, correct?

Comment: @p.liz, I'm not sure what you mean by "name variables".

Comment: jp_data_analysis I was being silly.  I have realised I was trying to loop to put all variables in for all files rather than loop the whole script and re-assign variables.